# I would like to know how I can get some fields in my db Mysql5.7 without using the faker technique in my controller (laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller

I would like to know how I can get some fields in my db Mysql5.7 without using the faker technique in my controller, my db is not yet populated, if my db was not populated and I did not use this technique?

```
class ClientsController extends Controller{

    public function index(){
    $clients = Client::all()
    return view(clients.index);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faker is for generating random fake data to get started with your logic implementation. There are so many ways you can generate data for your model. One is through bulk insert. You can add multiple arrays at a time in your seeder.

```
Client::insert([
   [// data],
   [// data],
   [// data],
   [// data],
   [// data]
]);
```

Populating fields with random data in controller is not a good option. I would recommend to use seeder without faker library with above code and when you migrate just add --seed parameter and it will work for you. You can use tinker too for this purpose. just paste the above code(with data arrays) in tinker and it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function index(){
  $clients = Client::all()
  return view('clients.index',['clients' => $clients]);
}
```